# In which disciplinary category can cryptography be put?

Tags: encryption

Is it a multi-disciplinary, inter-disciplinary, cross-disciplinary, or maybe even trans-disciplinary? What are the basis to describe each kind? I mean, how can we infer by which disciplinary field we can describe the cryptography?

I got an answer saying that it is multi-disciplinary because it contains multiple subjects like information theory, mathematics… what about the other fields?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question. Could you elaborate a bit? (The question has an edit button.) It also looks at the border to off-topic, though I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is multidisciplinary because it's a branch of mathematics and freely borrows from other branches such as statistics or algorithms.

I'm not so sure if it's cross-disciplinary. Although companies that make secure products (ie. products that use crypto facilities) employ cryptographers, cryptography in itself is a purely theoretical discipline that doesn't concern itself with implementation details that much (but Crypto.SE often does).

You could say it's interdisciplinary because it is a parent of quantum cryptography but I can't think of a justification for calling it cross-disciplinary.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discipline_(specialism)) has all the definitions you need by the way.